# fast way from 8bit grayscale numpy array to QPixmap

Tags: python, qt, numpy, pyside, qpixmap

I get a 2dimensional (800 x 600) numpy array every 0.5 sec. representing an greyscale image (8bit).

I tried converting it to PIL image and then using ImageQt to get a Pixmap, but ImageQt doesn't work ( I tried the sys.modules[.... hack, didn't go as well.)

Is there any tricky way to get a QPixmap or at least a QImage in a fast way? 
Mabye the QImage.fromdata method?

Thanks

Edit:

when i use the following i get a bluescale Image:

```
#input: data, 2dim numpy integer array
self.a = (255<<24 | data[:,:]<<16 | data[:,:]<<8 | data[:,:]).flatten()
self.qimg = QImage(self.a,800,600,QImage.Format_RGB32)
...#create pixmap and show it
```